# Hook your own button into "share list" for iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios4

When you take a picture or look at one in the album, there is a "share-button" visible. Is it possible to hook-in your own item to that list, so I can share the picture via my own app? If so, how do I do that?

There's an answer to this for Android, but I couldn't find this for iOS:
[Hook in your own item to the "share-list"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873173/hook-in-your-own-item-to-the-share-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register the fact that your app can open files of particular types, for more information here are Apple's docs about [registering your app](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010411-SW1) and [how to open the files](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/OpeningSupportedFileTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010412-SW1).

This is available from iOS 3.2 onwards

Comment: That means other apps would have to explicitly list my share button? What if I wanted to inject my own into Safari's share list for example (when you hold down on a link)?

Comment: Hmm, actually, I might have been wrong. It's possible for apps to do this using `UIDocumentInteractionController`, and I assumed that Photos and Safari made use of this, however I just checked it and it uses something else.


For your case, if you're looking at just sharing images then you can access the phone's photos by using `UIImagePickerController` from inside your app.

Answer (score 2):

There are no built-in classes that do this on iOS, but I suggest you try [ShareKit](http://getsharekit.com/). It is a joy to work with!